# Alembic drops indexes for foreign keys

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, alembic

I have a column `address_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey(Address.id, ondelete='CASCADE'), index=True)`. Autogenerating a migration with Alembic always adds a `drop_index` operation.

```
op.drop_index('address_id', 'companies')
```

Why does this happen every time I generate a migration?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a [known bug](https://bitbucket.org/zzzeek/alembic/issue/157/) in Alembic 0.6.1. Upgrade to 0.6.2 or newer and the problem will go away.